# Tool to work with indices in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, assign

I have the square matrix with elements, that can take values from `{-1, 0, 1}`. I know that there is only 1 element equals to -1 in every row (except the first row, where are only non-negative elements).

Let n be the size of the matrix.
So, I want to assign to every index `i` from `[2, n]` the position of -1 in `i`-th row from matrix.

How can I do this without using a `for` or `while` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = matrix==-1;
[~, pos] = max(t,[],2); %// position of first -1 within each row.
pos = pos .* any(t,2); %// give 0 for rows that don't contain any -1 value
```

`pos(k)` gives the position of the (first) `-1` value within row `k`, or `0` if there isn't any `-1` value in that row.

Example:

```
matrix =

     1     0     0     1
     0     1    -1     1
     0     1     1    -1
     0     0     1    -1
```

gives

```
pos =

     0
     3
     4
     4
```

Comment: @Jigg Because row 1 of `matrix==-1` contains all zeros, so `max` gives the position of the first 0, namely 1, which is wrong. Anyway, I've changed that to a more general approach.